# Adicionar caracter em um <input>

Tags: javascript, input, replace

A pessoa digita a altura dela(que sempre possui três dígitos).
Eu quero que autocomplete, exemplo:-

A pessoa digita- 200

E o software converta para- 2,00

Comment: Quando queres que converta? à medida que escreve, depois de x milisegundos sem carregar uma tecla ou quando o input perder o foco?

Comment: Na verdade você quer fazer uma mascara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se possui sempre 3 dígitos, então limite o `input` com o atributo `maxlength` que especifica o número máximo de caracteres que o usuário pode inserir.

`<input class="number" maxlength="3">`

**Javascript**

Não permite digitar valores diferentes de números e após digitar o terceiro número, insere a vírgula automaticamente após o primeiro número digitado.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('input.number');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
});
```

```html
<input class="number" maxlength=3>
```

Comment: Melhor que isso, só 2 disso :p